# Show that a generic line is not a leaf of an algebraic foliation of $\mathbb P^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, holomorphic-foliations

Consider a foliation of $\mathbb P^2$, whose leaves in the affine part $z = 1$ are the integral curves of a polynomial vector field

$$X = P \frac \partial {\partial x} + Q \frac \partial {\partial y}$$

How do I prove that a generic line $L \subset \mathbb P^2$ is not a leaf of this foliation?

Suppose I were allowed to fix a generic point $p \in \mathbb P^2$ and only then pick a generic line $L \subset \mathbb P^2$ passing through $p$. Then it is intuitively clear that

1. A generic point $p \in \mathbb P^2$ lies in the affine part $\mathbb C^2$.
2. A generic tangent vector $v \in T_p \mathbb C^2$, which plays the role of the tangent direction of $L$, is not parallel to $X(p)$.

But am I allowed to fix a generic point and only then pick a generic line passing through it in the first place? If so, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something about the language of "fixing a generic point" seems unpleasant to me. How about the following solution instead:

If no line in $\Bbb A^2$ is a leaf of the foliation, then a general line in $\Bbb P^2$ is not a leaf, as a general line passes through $\Bbb A^2$. If a line $\ell$ in $\Bbb A^2$ is a leaf of the foliation, then any line intersecting $\ell$ in $\Bbb A^2$ may not be a leaf of the foliation: leaves of the foliation are required to be smooth and non-intersecting. On the other hand, the condition of "intersects $\ell$ in $\Bbb A^2$" is a generic condition on the set of lines in $\Bbb P^2$. So a general line is not a leaf of this foliation.

Comment: This would work if the foliation had no singularities. But I think algebraic foliations of $\mathbb P^2$ necessarily have singularities. (Incidentally, now I realize that my argument is broken for the same reason.)

Comment: What is your definition of a foliation and a leaf of that foliation, then? (Also, the proof should work in the case of allowing singularities on the leaves: the condition of intersecting a line but not at some finite collection of specified points is still a general condition, and this applies here because the singularities of any 1-dim leaf would be a 0-dim set, or a finite collection of points.)

Comment: A foliation of $\mathbb P^2$ consists of the following data: (0) an open cover of $\mathbb P^2$, (1) for each open $U$ in the cover, a vector field $X_U$ on $U$, such that (2) for every pair of opens $U, V$ in the cover, the vector fields $X_U$ and $X_V$ are scalar multiples of one another on the overlap $U \cap V$.

Comment: And your definition of a leaf of the foliation?

Comment: A curve formed by pasting integral curves of the vector fields.

Comment: So in particular, it's maximal, right? That is, if you have a proper inclusion $C_1\subset C_2$, you can't call both $C_1$ and $C_2$ leaves. If you agree with this statement, then the proof in the answer goes through without modification. If not, then the parenthetical from the second comment should fix it.

Comment: Ah, okay, I see, thanks! (And, yes, leaves have to be maximal.)